# Cut part of string with replacment

Tags: php, string

I want to cut string with replacement

```
$string = "my super very long string";
$start = 3;
$end = 17;
```

I need cut from `$start` to `$end` and replace it with `$short = "short"`

Result must be `"my short string"`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [substr_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) like so:

```
$string = "my super very long string";
$short = "short";
$start = 3;
$end = 18;
$length = $end - $start;

$new_string = substr_replace($string, $short, $start, $length);
```

You can see a working example on this [codepad](http://codepad.org/cCIptSvr).

Whenever you want to do string manipulation, it's a good idea to take a look at the [string functions in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) to see if PHP has a function that does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

$string = "my super very long string";
$short = "short";
$start = 3;
$length = strlen("super very long");
$new_string = substr_replace($string,$short,$start,$end);
In the $new_string, you will get your desired output.

Answer (score -4):

```
$string = "my super very long string"; 
list($string1,$string2) = explode("super very long",$string);  
/*$string1 = my , $string2 =  string*/ 
$short = "short";
$new_string = $string1.$short.$string2; 
/*$new_string = my short string*/
```

Comment: working doesn't mean it's the best solution. The other solutions seem better.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's a good solution. Don't take the downvotes personally, they just mean people think it's not a preferrable solution.